# Setting contents of a text file to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I am trying to set a open a text file that is in a folder in my project.

See screen shot:
[image]

My code is as follows:

```
private void loadLog()
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath+"\\Version\\Version.log");
    string temp = File.ReadAllText(@fileName);
    txtVersionLog.Text = temp;
}
```

I am getting an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\psun\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\EDOrderImport\EDOrderImport\bin\Debug\Version\Version.log'.

My question is, am I in the right direction with this?

Comment: The question is, as Samy implies in his answer, does it work when running in Visual Studio? and is the path  'C:\Users\psun\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\EDOrderImport\EDOrderImport\bin\Debug\Version\Version.log' correct?

Comment: Loading the text file into a textbox will lose a lot of formatting, perhaps look into using an editor like http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 3):

Remember to set your text file ["Copy to output directory" property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer" (see the property pane for the file), if not it will stay in your solution directory structure and won't be replicated in the compiled output.

Answer (score 0):

"Version" folder should be in the same directory with your program/exe. Because Application.StartupPath is equals to your programs output path.